# Как отправить скрин и ссылку на статью aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

По задумке код должен в ответ на запрос юзера скинуть ему ссылку на результат и скрин, проскролив немного вниз.
Скрин сохраняет, но в ответ ничего не скидывает и падает с такой ошибкой.

Кто знает, поправьте, пожалуйста, заранее спасибо.

```py
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import Message, BufferedInputFile, FSInputFile
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


tok = 'он тут есть'
bot = Bot(tok)
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def get_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer(f'Привет,  {message.from_user.first_name}!')

@dp.message()
async def wikipars(message: Message):
    url = f'https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search= 
{message.text}&title=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F:
%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&ns0=1'
request = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('div', class_='mw-search-results-container')

if len(links) > 0:
    geturl = 'https://ru.wikipedia.org/' + links[0].find('a')['href']

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, 200)')
driver.save_screenshot('img.png')
driver.quit()
photo = FSInputFile('img.png')

await bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                        photo=photo,
                        caption=f'Ссылка на статью: <a href={geturl}> тык </a>',
                        parse_mode='HTML')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp.run_polling(bot)
```

Comment: С какой ошибкой?

Comment: Telegram server says - Bad Request: can't parse entities: Unclosed start tag at byte offset 32. Удалил капшн и парс мод, теперь скрин отправляет, после работы буду разбираться сидеть  почему ссыль не давал

Comment: Дополните вопрос. Внизу у него есть кнопка [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1560462/edit).